# syntax error (code 1): , while compiling:

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Есть главное активити в котором по нажатию на кнопку выполняется код:

```
package test.testdb;

import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.method.ScrollingMovementMethod;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.IOException;

import test.testdb.Contract.Entry;
import test.testdb.DBHeler;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView output;
    private EditText in;

    DBHeler db;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        db = new DBHeler(this);
        try {
            db.createDataBase();
            db.openDataBase();
        } catch (IOException ex) {

        }

        output = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.output);
        output.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
        in = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.in);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        db.close();
    }

    public void search() {
            String string = in.getText().toString().trim();
            String query = "SELECT " + Entry.COLUMN_COL2 + " FROM " + Entry.TABLE_NAME
                    + " WHERE " + Entry.COLUMN_COL1 + " = " + "\"" + string + "\"";
            Cursor cursor = db.database.rawQuery(query, null);
            output.setText("");
        if (!string.equals("")) {
            try {
                if (cursor.getCount() != 0) {
                    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                        int col2ColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(Entry.COLUMN_COL2);
                        String col2 = cursor.getString(col2ColumnIndex);
                        output.append(col2 + "\n\n");
                    }
                }
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
            } finally {
                cursor.close();
            }
        }
    }

    public void onClickBtnSearch(View view) {
        search();
    }
}
```

БД используется готовая, с БД все в порядке. Вот код класса, который использует эту БД

```
package test.testdb;

import android.provider.BaseColumns;

//Класс контракт. Используется для указания имени таблицы и полей таблицы

public class Contract implements BaseColumns {
    private Contract() {
    };

    public static final class Entry implements BaseColumns {
        public final static String TABLE_NAME = "table";

        public final static String COLUMN_COL1 = "col1";
        public final static String COLUMN_COL2 = "col2";
    }
}
```

---

```
package test.testdb;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.provider.BaseColumns;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class DBHeler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/test.testdb/databases/";
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "datab.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public SQLiteDatabase database;
    private Context myContext;

    public DBHeler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.myContext = context;
    }

    public void createDataBase() throws IOException{
        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

        if(dbExist){
        }else{
            this.getReadableDatabase();

            try {
                copyDataBase();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new Error("Error copying database");
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean checkDataBase(){
        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
        try {
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        } catch(SQLiteException e){
        }
        if(checkDB != null){
            checkDB.close();
        }
        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }

    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{
        InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();
    }

    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
        database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {
        if(database != null)
            database.close();
        super.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    }
}
```

Но при нажатии кнопки выдает ошибку

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: test.testdb, PID: 2411
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610)
  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22265)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610) 
  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22265) 
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755) 
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "table": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT col2 FROM table WHERE col1 = "мама"
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1318)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1257)
  at test.testdb.MainActivity.search(MainActivity.java:52)
  at test.testdb.MainActivity.onClickBtnSearch(MainActivity.java:71)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610) 
  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22265) 
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

Подскажите где что не так? Вроде все нормально в строчке где rawQuery

Answer (score 3):

Написано же совершенно ясно:

> near "table": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT col2 FROM table WHERE col1 = "мама"

Не только сообщение об ошибке приведено, но и сам ошибочный запрос. Ничего в нём не замечаете?

Слово `TABLE` является ключевым в SQL. Если уж пришла в голову странная мысль дать таблице такое имя, то в запросе нужно ставить обратные кавычки:

```
SELECT `col2` FROM `table` WHERE `col1` = "мама"
```

Но лучше таких имён не давать ни таблицам, ни их полям, ни чему-то ещё. Не в смысле имён `TABLE`, а имён, совпадающих с ключевыми словами в принципе.

Comment: А регистр роли не играет?

Comment: @post_zeew, никак не влияет.

Comment: [Странно](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27998608/7129209).

Comment: @post_zeew, а в какой версии SQL / на какой базе такой  `CREATE` взлетит? Проверил на postgres, sqlte3 и maria,  нигде не работает. С обратными кавычками - да.

Comment: Да по идее не должно нигде, но это была и не критика, если что :) Просто смутил ответ на en.SO.

Comment: Изменил название таблицы. Все равно тоже самое

Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: tab (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT col2 FROM tab WHERE col1 = "мама"

Comment: В другом примере без каких-то обратных кавычек все работало. А тут не пойму в чем причина. Теперь то запрос правильный

Comment: @kolhoz, вы вообще не пытаетесь понять, что содержится в сообщении об ошибке? "no such table: tab" переводится как "нет такой таблицы". На какой ещё язык вам перевести чтобы понятней стало?

Comment: я это прекрасно понял. Но такая таблица есть.

Comment: @kolhoz, Поднимите версию схемы БД: `DATABASE_VERSION = 2`.

Comment: не помогло все равно.

Comment: Блин заново создал БД с теми же полями и таблицей все заработало